# Hash of array dynamic

Tags: ruby, arrays, dynamic, hash

I have to create an array during runtime which is stored in a hash. 
How can I achieve this in a smart way ?
Following code does not work since services[...] is not an array.

```
services = {}
services["clean"] << 'bathroom'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to Neil Slater's syntax, you can use:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

to instantiate a hash with a default value of `[]`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Much better syntax. Except it does auto-vivify on all key lookups when you might not want that.

Comment: For an hash of hash of array:
services = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new { |hash2, key2| hash2[key2] =  []} }

Comment: @der_wolle - "auto-vivify" means it will create the default key/value in the hash due to any reference in any part of the code. E.g. `h["unwanted_key"]` just on its own would give you a hash `h == { "unwanted_key" => [] }`. This might be a problem if you have code elsewhere relying on getting `nil`, or expecting to raise an error for a missing key. As long as you know this is the new hash behaviour and use `h.has_key?` to check for key existing, it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

I might do something like this:

```
( services["#{service['service']}"] ||= [] ) << service['attributes']
```

This would not work if you want to store `nil` or `false` in your hash, as it relies on the truthiness of `nil` returned when there is no matching key being false, in order for the `||=` operation to trigger assigning a new empty array.

Not sure if there is nicer syntax.